# gn scripts are run with the wrong Python version ("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'")

Tags: chromium, build-system, build-script, gn

When building Chromium or libwebrtc with `gn` on macOS (Catalina 10.15), I get errors from the Python build scripts about `bytes` and `str`. For example:

```
src [heads/master●] % gn gen out/ios_64 --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64"'
ERROR at //build/config/ios/ios_sdk.gni:109:21: Script returned non-zero exit code.
  _ios_sdk_result = exec_script(script_name, ios_sdk_info_args, "scope")
                    ^----------
Current dir: /Users/lynn/code/webrtc_ios/src/out/ios_64/
Command: python /Users/lynn/code/webrtc_ios/src/build/config/mac/sdk_info.py --get_sdk_info iphoneos
Returned 1.
stderr:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lynn/code/webrtc_ios/src/build/config/mac/sdk_info.py", line 107, in <module>
    FillXcodeVersion(settings, args.developer_dir)
  File "/Users/lynn/code/webrtc_ios/src/build/config/mac/sdk_info.py", line 59, in FillXcodeVersion
    settings['xcode_version'] = FormatVersion(lines[0].split()[-1])
  File "/Users/lynn/code/webrtc_ios/src/build/config/mac/sdk_info.py", line 43, in FormatVersion
    major, minor, patch = SplitVersion(version)
  File "/Users/lynn/code/webrtc_ios/src/build/config/mac/sdk_info.py", line 30, in SplitVersion
    version = version.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

See //build/config/sysroot.gni:67:3: whence it was imported.
  import("//build/config/ios/ios_sdk.gni")
  ^--------------------------------------
See //build/config/linux/pkg_config.gni:5:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/sysroot.gni")
^----------------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:15:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/linux/pkg_config.gni")
^-------------------------------------------
```

When I edit the offending Python script to `print(sys.version)`, it shows that it is running Python 3, even though the scripts are supposed to running with the bundled virtual Python 2.7 environment defined in `.vpython`.

How do I configure `gn` to run these scripts with the appropriate Python version?

Answer (score 11):

It seems `exec_script` is running these scripts with the machine Python version. `gn help exec_script` says:

> The default script interpreter is Python ("python" on POSIX, "python.exe" or
>     "python.bat" on Windows). This can be configured by the script_executable
>     variable, see "gn help dotfile".

For me, `python` points to Python 3. So I had to add this line to the end of the .gn dotfile:

```
script_executable = "vpython"
```

Now the build uses the virtual Python defined in `.vpython`, which is Python 2.7.

(The `vpython` executable is provided by Chromium depot_tools, just like `gn`.)

Comment: Please tell me where is the .gn dotfile located?

Comment: @user2801184 It depends on your project. For me it was in the root-level `src` directory, so `src/.gn` .

Comment: Thanks alot. Helped me resolve


```ninja: Entering directory `C:/projects/v8go/deps/.build/windows_x86_64'
<< cut for brevity >>
TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.```